# Difference between IS FALSE and = 'f' in Postgres and index use

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In Postgres 9.6, on a users table with around 12 million rows, where the `active` boolean column has a btree index on it.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 'f' LIMIT 1;

Limit  (cost=0.00..0.14 rows=1 width=982) (actual time=0.039..0.040 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..3190979.68 rows=23264168 width=982) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (NOT active)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 115
Planning time: 0.161 ms
Execution time: 0.067 ms
```

But, using `IS FALSE` seems to use the index.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM users WHERE active IS FALSE LIMIT 1;

Limit  (cost=0.44..0.59 rows=1 width=982) (actual time=0.054..0.056 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using index_users_on_active on users  (cost=0.44..2059.14 rows=13183 width=982) (actual time=0.051..0.051 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (active = false)
        Filter: (active IS FALSE)
Planning time: 0.170 ms
Execution time: 0.094 ms
```

The vast majority of the records, the active value is `true`, and I understand an index isn't always faster.

It seems that Rails prefers the `active = 'f'` syntax, as that's what it outputs when you build a query.

Why are these different? How are they different? Should the other ever be used?

Comment: Please elaborate on what Rails prefers.

Comment: `User.where(active: false).limit(1).to_sql` returns 

`SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."active" = 'f' LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 21):

The difference is in how NULL values are handled. Per the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html):

- `IS FALSE` will always return a boolean value, even if the argument is null.
- `= 'f'` will return null if the argument is null.

So to illustrate,

```
rnubel=# SELECT NULL = 'f' as equals_false, NULL IS FALSE as is_false;

 equals_false | is_false
--------------+----------
              | f
```

Generally, most things in SQL will operate on a ternary-logic basis, where null values produce null results; so it's not surprising that Rails defaults to using the operator consistent with that basis. However, it's different from what you'd expect in Ruby (where `!nil == true`), so it's likely been the cause of much unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to oppose my answer to the one from Robert Nubel. Despite the fact that comparison `null = false` will return null, it will not affect the resulting set:

```
t=> with b(v) as (values(true),(false),(null))
mon-> select v,v::text from b;
 v |   v
---+-------
 t | true
 f | false
   |
(3 rows)

t=> with b(v) as (values(true),(false),(null))
select v,v::text from b where v is false;
 v |   v
---+-------
 f | false
(1 row)

t=> with b(v) as (values(true),(false),(null))
select v,v::text from b where not v;;
 v |   v
---+-------
 f | false
(1 row)

t=> with b(v) as (values(true),(false),(null))
select v,v::text from b where v = 'f';
 v |   v
---+-------
 f | false
(1 row)
```

The difference in execution plans was due to index condition hit (`Index Cond: (active = false)`)

Comment: A good point, though the two are not always equivalent. For example, compare `SELECT EVERY(v IS FALSE)` vs `SELECT EVERY(v = 'f')` when the values are just `false` and `null` -- you'll get back false for the first, but true for the latter. The difference in behavior, though subtle, explains why Postgres does not take advantage of the index.